# How to pass the current value of a variable into a function scope?

Tags: r

How can I construct a function using the current value of a variable?

Here is an example:

```
x <- 2
f <- function() { return(x) }
x <- 3
f() # evaluates to 3 as expected, but I'd like it to evaluate to 2.
```

Comment: What do you mean by `current value`. The current value when the function was created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where R's lexical scoping comes in handy:

```
MakeF <- function() {
  x <- x
  f <- function() {
    return(x)
  }
  return(f)
}

x <- 2
f <- MakeF()
x <- 3
```

Which gives:

```
> f()
[1] 2
```

Comment: A slightly shorter version would use `local` instead of a function creating a function.  But the overall concept is the same.  The `force` function may also be of interest.